# iOS - 3-letter Timezone abbreviation for NSTimeZone

Tags: ios, objective-c

How can I get three letter abbreviations in iOS for a TimeZone

`[NSTimeZone abbreviationDictionary]` gives abbreviation as 3-letter code. For eg:

`NSZT`, `PDT`, `EST` etc.

However,

```
NSString * ss = [NSTimeZone timeZoneWithName:@"Pacific/Auckland"].abbreviation;
```

gives **`GMT+12`**.

Is there a way I can get **`NSZT/NZDT`** instead?

Comment: `abbreviationDictionary` only has 51 entries while `knownTimeZoneNames` has 437. If you create an `NSTimeZone` from each of those 437 names and get the `abbreviation`, only 102 return an abbreviation that isn't a GMT offset (and 99 of those start with "America/"). Of the 335 without a useful abbreviation, only 28 of them are listed in `abbreviationDictionary`. In other words, of the 437 timezone names, you can only get a useful abbreviation from 130 of them.

Comment: I need know 3 letter abbreviations for Africa/Nairobi, Any solution for this, Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You can get a full standard localized name of timezone using below code

**Objective c:**

```
NSTimeZone* timeZone = [NSTimeZone timeZoneWithName:@"Pacific/Auckland"];
NSString* timeZoneName = [timeZone localizedName:NSTimeZoneNameStyleStandard
                                              locale:[NSLocale currentLocale]];
NSLog(@"%@", timeZoneName);
```

**Swift:**

```
let timezone:TimeZone = TimeZone.init(identifier: "Pacific/Auckland") ?? TimeZone.current
print(timezone.localizedName(for: .generic, locale: .autoupdatingCurrent))
print(timezone.localizedName(for: .standard, locale: .autoupdatingCurrent))
```

**Output:**

> **Objective c:**
>
> New Zealand Standard Time
>
> **Swift:**
>
> Optional("New Zealand Standard Time")
>
> Optional("New Zealand Standard Time")

I think now you can get `NZST` from New Zealand Standard Time by splitting and combining string

**Objective c:**

```
NSMutableString * firstCharacters = [NSMutableString string];
NSArray *wordsArray = [timeZoneName componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceCharacterSet]];
for (NSString * word in wordsArray){
 if ([word length] > 0){
    NSString * firstLetter = [word substringToIndex:1];
    [firstCharacters appendString:[firstLetter uppercaseString]];
 }
}
NSLog(@"%@", firstCharacters);
```

**Swift:**

```
let fullName = timezone.localizedName(for: .standard, locale: .autoupdatingCurrent) ?? ""
var result = ""
fullName.enumerateSubstrings(in: fullName.startIndex..<fullName.endIndex, options: .byWords) { (substring, _, _, _) in
    if let substring = substring { result += substring.prefix(1) }
}
print(result)
```

**Output:**

> NZST

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comment by rmaddy abbreviationDictionary only has 51 entries, but if you use only names from the abbreviationDictionary you can use following code:

```
NSDictionary *dict = [NSTimeZone abbreviationDictionary];
NSArray *abbreviations = [dict allKeysForObject:@"Pacific/Auckland"];
if (abbreviations.count > 0) {
  NSLog(@"%@", abbreviations.firstObject);
}
```